# iOS linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error for Adhoc scheme

Tags: ios

I am having problem building my project with ADHOC scheme. Everything works fine (Debug and release schemes).
Error:

```
Ld /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cfuhpfaznacxuqbiacxarbbrnanq/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Adhoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp normal armv7
    cd "/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp tee booking copy/MyApp_ios"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk -L/Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cfuhpfaznacxuqbiacxarbbrnanq/Build/Products/Adhoc-iphoneos -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/ParseCrashReporting -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/GoogleConversionTrackingSDK-iOS-3.2.0 -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/GoogleConversionTrackingSDK-iOS-3.4.0 -F/Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cfuhpfaznacxuqbiacxarbbrnanq/Build/Products/Adhoc-iphoneos -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/Google/Frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleAppUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleAuthUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/HockeySDKCrashOnly -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp\ tee\ booking\ copy/MyApp_ios/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDKCrashOnly -filelist /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cfuhpfaznacxuqbiacxarbbrnanq/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Adhoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cfuhpfaznacxuqbiacxarbbrnanq/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Adhoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp_lto.o -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -ObjC -lBolts -lGoogleAnalytics -lMZAppearance -lMZFormSheetPresentationController -lParse -lParseCrashReporting -lParseCrashReportingLib -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lstdc++.6 -lz -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBook -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreText -framework Crashlytics -framework Fabric -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework Foundation -framework GGLCore -framework GGLSignIn -framework GoogleAppUtilities -framework GoogleAuthUtilities -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleNetworkingUtilities -framework GoogleSignIn -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -framework MessageUI -framework CoreFoundation -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework UIKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework SystemConfiguration -framework SafariServices -framework AddressBook -framework CoreBluetooth -framework Accelerate -framework AdSupport -lsqlite3 -framework QuartzCore -framework AudioToolbox -framework GoogleMaps -lstdc++.6 -lz -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -lsqlite3.0 -lc++ -framework FBSDKCoreKit -licucore -framework MapKit -lGoogleConversionTracking -framework GLKit -framework OpenGLES -framework ImageIO -framework CoreData -framework AVFoundation -lPods-MyApp -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cfuhpfaznacxuqbiacxarbbrnanq/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Adhoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cfuhpfaznacxuqbiacxarbbrnanq/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Adhoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp tee booking copy/MyApp_ios/GoogleConversionTrackingSDK-iOS-3.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp tee booking copy/MyApp_ios/HockeySDKCrashOnly'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp tee booking copy/MyApp_ios/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/MyApp tee booking copy/MyApp_ios/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDKCrashOnly'
ld: library not found for -lBolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I edit my Adhoc scheme and set run configuration to Debug, project builds successfully. What is the problem?

Comment: If you select "Debug", do you also run on a device or on the simulator? Because the architecture changes from i386 (Simulator) to armv7/armv7s, arm64 on iOS devices

Comment: Have you tried to delete `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and restarting Xcode?

Comment: @Lepidopteron Yes I can run on simulator or device.

Comment: @TomKraina I deleted Derived Data manually but didn't help.

Comment: Edited my error description.

Comment: Did you link all the libraries to your Ad-Hoch build rules? Go to the Project's main setings and check the different build configurations and linked libraries

Comment: What do you mean by "Did you link all the libraries to your Ad-Hoch build rules?". What am I supposed to check in linked libraries?